# how to test search concept in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to test Rspec for a search function,
this is what I have so far,

```
def product_search
    filter = ""
    filter = filter + " and B.sku like '#{params[:sku]}%'" if params[:sku]  && params[:sku] != ""
    filter = filter + " and A.name like '#{params[:name]}%'" if params[:name] && params[:name] != ""
    filter = filter + " and D.name like '#{params[:store_name]}%'" if params[:store_name] && params[:store_name] != ""
    if params[:approved] == "0"
        filter= filter + "and (A.is_approved = false And A.approved_by is NULL) "
    elsif params[:approved] == "1"
        filter= filter + "and A.is_approved = true "
    elsif params[:approved] == "2"
        filter= filter + " and (A.is_approved = false And A.approved_by is NOT NULL) "
    end
  @products=Product.seller_product_search(filter,current_user.store.id).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js 
    end
end
```

How should I write rspec for this code ?

Answer (score 1):

i would put the whole search-logic into the Product model and pass the params hash to this.

then i would create a method to test this in the model spec. this should be pretty straight forward.

what is the problem that you are experiencing?

Comment: if this is your problem, then have a look at all those resources available on the net: http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=7 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html etc...

Comment: hey @phoet i did some work like you said in answer, and now confuse to start test, can you please have  look that test you type down ever ?